# YouTube API key is not working after uploading android App in play store. Its working properly before uploading in Genymotion and all Android Emulator

Tags: android, firebase, android-youtube-api

YouTube API key is not working after uploading android App in play store. Its working properly before uploading in Genymotion and all Android Emulator.[image]

Before Uploading to play store

[image]

After Uploading to play store

Comment: How is this question related to Firebase?

Comment: google-service .json download from firebase.

Answer (score 1):

## In build.gradle

```
configurations {
    all {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    }
... 
}
```

## In proguard-rules.pro

```
-keep class com.google.api.** { *; }
-keepparameternames
-ignorewarnings
```

Comment: Thanks! I only added the rules to proguard-rules.pro and it worked.